# Navbar issue Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have been trying the whole day to make my first navbar to work using bootstrap example, but I still cant make the button work... any tips? please...

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">

<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-target=".navbar-collapse">           

    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <h1>Tim Berners-Lee <small>El genio detras del internet</small></h1>
</div>


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Biografia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contexto Historico</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Referencias</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What button? Please, define what you mean with "doesn't work". What should it do?

Comment: The button 'works' for me (on smaller screens it shows and slides down the menu) http://jsbin.com/gadoq/1/

Comment: The button for opening the <ul> with <li> it should be able to open like a dropdown menu, at least its supposed to do that

Comment: it dosnt work for me I dont know why, and I cant upload images to show exactly what I mean

Comment: Put the images on [imgur](http://imgur.com/).  Does your instance behave different to the example I linked to?  If so, do you have links to the Bootstrap JS / CSS included?

Comment: hmm can you copy for me the exact links I should be using all the times? please... just to make sure im doing links well (im just complete new to boots)

Comment: For the CSS you need this (if you want a CDN rather than local files) `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">`.  Then you need the jquery library, and after that, the Bootstrap minified JS (again, this is from CDN).
`<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`.  All of this documented in the Getting started, which it is presumed you read before starting to build something using Bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working demo with your exact HTML.  http://cdpn.io/DJwdH

Everything looks good with that so the next things to check are:

1 - you are including jQuery and that the path is correct
2 - after including jQuery you include the Bootstrap JS file ( jQuery must load first)
3 - you have included the Bootstrap CSS file

Good luck!